# Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg $4(5)$ method adaptive size $h$ - iterating too much

Tags: mathematical-physics, computational-mathematics, runge-kutta-methods

I tried to solve baryocentric two body problem with Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg with adaptive size method.

I have two differential equations

$$ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = - \frac{\mu}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}} $$

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = - \frac{\mu}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}} $$

My initial conditions are

$$ \mu = 3.98 x 10^5 km^3/s^2 $$
$$ x_0 = -2500 km $$
$$ y_0 = -5500 km $$
$$ v_{x0} = 7.5 km/s $$
$$ v_{y0} = 0.5km/s $$

Relative Error =  $$10^{-2}$$

Thanks to @Lutz Lehmann I fixed the error and edited the code.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate, linalg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Constants
mu          = 3.98 *10**5

lowerBoundT = 0
upperBoundT = 100000

relHata = 10**(-2)
#                   X0          Y0          VX0         VY0
initialValues = [   -2500,      -5500,      7.5,        0.5     ]

def two_body(t, p):
    x, y, vx, vy = p
    return np.array([vx, vy, -mu * x / (x**2 + y**2)**1.5, -mu * y / (x**2 + y**2)**1.5])

def rkf45Vec(fVec,initialT, initialY, tStop, n, relHata):
    tAll = np.array([initialT])
    yAll = np.array([[initialY]])

    h = (tStop - initialT) / n
    y = initialY
    t = initialT

    def calculateK(t, y, h):
        h_new = h
        h_prev = h
        k = 0
        while True:
            k0 = h_new * fVec(t            , y)
            k1 = h_new * fVec(t + 1/4*h    , y + 1/4*k0)
            k2 = h_new * fVec(t + 3/8*h    , y + 3/32*k0 + 9/32*k1)
            k3 = h_new * fVec(t + 12/13*h  , y + 1932/2197*k0 - 7200/2197*k1 + 7296/2197*k2)
            k4 = h_new * fVec(t + h        , y + 439/216*k0 - 8*k1 + 3680/513*k2 - 845/4104*k3)
            k5 = h_new * fVec(t + 1/2*h    , y - 8/27*k0 + 2*k1 - 3544/2565*k2 + 1859/4104*k3 - 11/40*k4)
            k = 25/216*k0 + 1408/2565*k2 + 2197/4104*k3 - 1/5*k4

            # Compute the error estimate and the new step size
            delta = np.abs(k0/360 - 128*k2/4275 - 2197*k3/75240 + k4/50 + 2*k5/55)
            s = 0.84*(relHata/delta)**0.25
            maxDelta = np.max(s)
            h_new = h * np.min(s)

            # Update the solution
            if maxDelta > relHata:
                break
            h_prev = h_new

        return k, h_new, h_prev

    iterationCount = 0
    while t < tStop:
        iterationCount += 1
        k, h_new, h_prev = calculateK(t,y,h, 1)

        y = y + k
        t = t + h_prev

        h = h_new
        tAll = np.append(tAll, t)
        yAll = np.append(yAll, y)
    yAll = yAll.reshape((len(tAll), len(initialY)))
    print(f'rkf45Vec step count={n}  {iterationCount} times iterated')
    return tAll, yAll

rkf45Vec_100 = rkf45Vec(two_body, lowerBoundT, initialValues, upperBoundT, 100, relHata)
```

[My differentational equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TooZ.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In the formula for `k5`you have `t+1/2` instead of `t+1/2*h`. This should have no influence here. /// See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586930/variable-step-runge-kutta-methods-fehlberg-vs-dormand-prince-why-is-the-order/4586967#4586967, your step size formula is wrong for updating with the 4th order step.

Comment: So the critical error was the sign of the k4 term in the computation of delta. The step size computation is still inappropriate, but apparently less critical. To see that you would need to store the local error estimate or even compute a more precise estimate and compare this to the error threshold `relHata` or `0.84**4*relHata`. With `h_new = 0.84 * h_prev * (relHata*h_prev/magnitudeDelta)**(1/4)` you should get a more even error curve.

Comment: Your guessing at improvements enters the stage of diminishing returns. You need to compare same with same, so the maxDelta should be the maximum over delta. The update formula for h_new is relative to the last step size, the initial step size gives a wrong value. Clearing this up should give you results also for smaller error tolerances.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the appropriate step size formula for the method you use. The error tolerance `relHata` is a bound or guide for the unit step error. The conversion from the local step error to the unit step error is to divide by $h$. This extrapolates the error from the interval of length $h$ to an interval of length $1$.

Also, for the relative error to be relative, you have to scale it by the size of the component, either the current size or a moving average of it.

Remaining in your code structure, I would organize the step size control code as

```
while True:
    k4, k5, err = RKF45_offsets(f,t,y,h_new)
    scale = abs(y)+abs(k4)
    rho = relHata*h_new*min(scale/abs(err))
    h_prev = h_new
    h_new = 0.84 * rho**0.25 * h_prev
    if 0.01 < rho < 1.2:
        break
return k4, h_new, h_prev
```